# Usage of preposition in word "invest"

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage, prepositions

I am Korean English learner:)

Here is my question.

> However, last year, my university **invested** a significant amount of money **to** introduce a greater number or healthy food options at its cafeterias.

This sentence is from the TOEFL passage.

I am curious about the word **invest** in this sentence. 
I learned we use preposition "in" after the word "invest". 
However, in this sentence I cannot find "in" but "to".

Thus I found this usage and meaning in the dictionary, and it said using **invest** both < invest + object + pp > and < invest + object >. 
I think the sentence used **invest** as usage of < invest + object + pp > then why there is no **in** in the sentence but **to**? (before the introduce)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you learned there is absolutely correct. Most of the time, we do use the preposition *in* after the verb *invest*. The preposition *into* is also possible, but *in* is used a lot more commonly. However, the *to* that you're talking about there is not a preposition at all. It's something called [**an infinitive marker**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/infinitive_marker) which goes along with the verb *introduce* and indicates that the verb *introduce* is being used in its infinitive form (for example, *to buy*, *to see* and *to watch* are all the infinitive forms of the verbs *buy*, *see* and *watch* respectively). One of the goals of using verbs in their infinitive forms is to specify the purpose of an action. For instance, *to see* in *I went there to see the man* specifies the purpose of the action of going there. I went there for the purpose of seeing the man. Consider this sentence:

> They **invested** lots of money in the company **to make** even more money.

Now, I will ask you the following question what was **the purpose of** them investing lots of money in the company? The answer you should give would be the purpose of them investing lots of money in the company was **to make** even more money. Do you see how this works?

So, we could rewrite your sentence like this:

> However, last year, my university invested a significant amount of money (in its infrastructure) **for the purpose of introducing** a greater number of healthy food options at its cafeterias.

Comment: "investing lots of many" ...  "to make even more money"? Is it a typo or slang? Not being ironic.

Comment: Neither a type nor slang. They're just greedy people. They have a lot of money, but they want to have even more money.

Comment: many, you have written "many" twice instead of "money"

Comment: "They're just greedy people". I agree.

Answer (score 1):

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/invest)

**to invest**

> to put money, effort, time, etc. **into** something **to** make a profit or
>   get an advantage

Notice that I've marked two words above: **into** and **to**.

**into** (or in) marks what you buy, **to** marks what you expect to gain with your investment.

Let me rephrase your sentence

> However, last year, my university invested a significant amount of
>   money **in new vending machines** to introduce a greater number or healthy food options at its
>   cafeterias.

Well, maybe "vending machines" is not a good option, but I don't know what exactly bought that university. Lots of carrots? Please, suggests items that this university may have adquired and I gladly will edit my post. :-)

Comment: thank you!!!:) it really helps me to understand the usage!

Comment: @Belle You can "accept" an answer. (It doesn't have to be this one) It will mark it with a green tick informing other users that you have considered that one the most useful for your purposes. You can change the accepted one if another more useful answers appears after.